# Georeferencing NASA, NOAA, and Natural Earth Projections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I'm new to QGIS. I'm currently using the newest version-- 3.10. I downloaded a raster projection (a tiff file) and vector data (SHP files of coastlines and rivers) from Natural Earth I to import as layers into QGIS. These opened correctly.

Then I downloaded several Plate Caree (WGS 84) projections from NASA Visible Earth and Natural Earth III. I could not find GeoTiff versions, so these are JPEGs. [On the Natural Earth III website it did have a folder with georeference data-- a text file and .tfw file.]  I've tried two methods for Georeferencing these:

1. Using the pulldown menus: Raster > Conversion > Translate (Convert Format).. I selected Plate Caree. It appeared to work correctly, but when I added the vector layer with rivers, the vector layer appears tiny compared to the Natural Earth layer.
2. I used the 'Georeferencer' plug-in. It took a long time, and I still was not sure if I had done it correctly. This time when I tried opening the Rivers Vector layer, I could not see that layer at all.

Is there a way to quickly and accurately georeference a world map that is in JPEG form if you know the CRS?

NASA and NOAA mainly use Plate Caree, so is there a way I can tell QGIS that is the map I am using, so it accept the CRS?

Comment: Please provide a link to the "plate caree" datasets you downloaded.

Comment: NOTE: I could not get a raster map georeferenced in QGIS 3.10.1. This week (ending 2 Feb 20), I saw a message from the QGIS team that there were issues with the georeferencing features in version 3.10.1. I upgraded to QGIS 3.10.2, and the issues I was having seem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

**About the Tom Patterson - Natural Earth III project**

The *.twf* file is used to georeference *TIFF* files, but the site is providing *JPEG* files. Also, the name of the world file must be the same as the image file.

So, if you download the [3_no_ice_clouds_8k.jpg](http://shadedrelief.com/natural3/ne3_data/8192/textures/3_no_ice_clouds_8k.jpg) file, you must unzip the [projection.zip](http://shadedrelief.com/natural3/ne3_data/projection.zip) file, copy the *8192x4036.tfw* file to the same folder as the image, and rename it as: *3_no_ice_clouds_8k.jgw*.

Next, you can load the *JPEG* file to QGIS and it will be georeferenced.

The text file says that it is defined in *LatLong* of a *6370997 m* radius sphere, from *WGS84* datum.
You can set the *EPSG:4052 (Unespecified datum based upon the Clark 1866 Authalic Sphere)* CRS to the layer and export it to any format and CRS that you want.

---

**About NOAA produts and NASA Visible Earth project**

There are a lot of images in the Visible Earth project, but seems to me not intended to be georeferenced.

Nevertheless, for some of them you will find the *GeoTIFF* version, e.g. [the Blue Marble Bathimetry](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73963/bathymetry).

Some NASA-NOAA sensors have specific projections associated, e.g. the GOES-16 project delivers its products in a geostationary projection. The georeferenced raw data can be downloaded from their project server.

If you have any doubt about any specific product, feel free to open a new question post about it.

---

In all cases, when managing images as raster layers, you can create their [World File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) by hand to georeference, load the layer and set its CRS in QGIS.